# How to print "-n" without issuing a newline?

Tags: bash, echo

I'm trying to print `-n` using the `echo` command. But if i simply type `echo -n`, it only issues a newline, not show up `-n`, instead it issues a newline.

Comment: Does `echo -n -- -n` work (don't have any linux box handy to test)?

Comment: I'm installing Ubuntu in a virtual machine and it seems to be very slow, wait.

Comment: I've checked - it does not. Probably because it's internal bash command and it's not using `getopt` (???) to parse command line

Comment: This question is asked and answered in http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html - - "Conforming applications that ... could possibly be expecting to echo a -n, should use the printf utility derived from the Ninth Edition system"

Comment: First popular question i have made. Yay?

Comment: ... 100 reputation on all of my communities? Nice reward, moderators!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The problem is that `echo` interprets the `-n` as an argument. On the default bash implementation, that means (from `help echo`):

> ```
>   -n  do not append a newline
> ```

There are various ways of getting around that:

1. Make it into something that isn't an option by including another character. For example, tell `echo` not to print a newline with `-n`, then tell it to interpret backslash escapes with `-e` and add the newline explicitly.

   ```
   $ echo -ne '-n\n'
   -n
   ```
2. Alternatively, just include a space

   ```
   $ echo " -n"
    -n
   ```

   That, however, adds a space which you probably don't want.
3. Use a non-printing character before it. Here. I am using the backspace (`\b`)

   ```
   $ echo -e "\b-n"
   -n
   ```

   This also adds an extra character you probably don't want.
4. Use trickery

   ```
   $ echo n- | rev
   -n
   ```

   The `rev` command simply prints its output reversed.
5. Use [the right tool for the job](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/22222)

   ```
   $ printf -- '-n\n'
   -n
   ```

Comment: You are correct that any `\\` valid character will do.

Comment: @Pilot6 yeah but the problem with that approach (yours and mine) is that it adds an extra character. That can cause issues down the line. Especially if you then want to parse it and try something like `grep '^-n'`. `pritnf` is the way to go, really.

Comment: Well, `printf` is better anyway, but the question is regarding just `echo`.

Comment: It looks like `echo -e "-n\c"` does the exact thing.

Comment: @Pilot6 nice! What is `\c`? I don't see it in `man ascii`. Also, I just realized that `echo -ne '-n\n'` prints `-n\n` and only that, just as desired.

Comment: `\c` is suppress further output

Comment: @Pilot6 ah, it's an echo-specific thing. Good to know, thanks!

Comment: `\b` is backspace, `\a` is a bell.

Answer (score 16):

Sometimes it's a good idea to use the right tool. You could use `printf` instead:

```
% printf "-n\n"       
-n
```

Comment: This is a good idea, since [there are many variants of `echo`, while `printf` is better standardized](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/17535).

Comment: This is a preferred idea for portability

Answer (score 7):

You can use this command, but it adds an extra space.

```
echo -e  "\r-n"
```

This is a kind of a hack.

`-e` enables backslash command symbols.

`\r` is a carriage return.

Actually any `\` valid character will do in any place of the string.

You can see which are valid by `help echo`.

`echo "-n"` does not work because `-n` is used as a parameter for `echo`.

**P.S.** The best solution IMHO is

```
echo -e "-n\c"
```

It does not add **any extra characters**.

```
echo -e "-n\n"
```

prints the same but with a new line char.

Comment: Wov! This is better than mine; can you explain a bit for "beginners" ;-)

Comment: Thanks, I've also noticed that it doesn't matter where you add the carriage return, at the beginning or the end.

Comment: @Sadi yes, that's because adding anything makes it a non-valid option. `-n` is valid, `-nfoo` is not so that will be printed.

Comment: @terdon `man echo` has it too. But `help` is a bit better.

Comment: I know it has it, it's just not relevant. `/bin/echo` is a completely different thing and when you run `echo` in bash, you get the builtin which can be quite different depending on your shell.

Comment: You can also print the extra character, and then erase it: `echo -e "- \x08n"`

Answer (score 5):

I think if you definitely want to use `echo` only, this should satisfy you:

```
echo "-n "
```

This works because while `-n` is a valid option for `echo`, `-n` with a space after it is not. Since it isn't an option, `echo` just prints it.

Comment: Most viewers here may only want "-n", not "-n ".

Answer (score 5):

You guys are really overthinking it.

```
 echo -e \\055n
```

Or with no trailing newline

```
 echo -en \\055n
```

Comment: How is `printf "-n\n" ` an overthinking?

Comment: Yup, I just answered this way. Will delete my answer. This is relatively portable in that it works with built-in echo and `/bin/echo` at least if invoked as `echo -e "\055n"`

Comment: -en is not what i want.

Answer (score 2):

In Bash script you can run:

```
echo -n -
echo n
```

Or in interacive shell:

```
echo -n - ; echo n
```

This `echo`es a `-` character and an `n` character.

Comment: Did you try it? It is wrong.

Comment: @Pilot6 [Did you try it? It is *not* wrong.](https://ideone.com/sPtlG4)

Comment: First command outputs `-pilot6@Pilot6:~$`. The second  outputs `n`.

Comment: @Pilot6 Depends on whether you're running it in interactive terminal or in a bash script, which isn't specified in the question. OTOH if you need it in the terminal it is simple to just combine the two lines with `&&` - I wouldn't really say this answer is *wrong*.

Comment: I'll edit it so it becomes much clearer it's for a bash script.

Comment: This uses trickery. You can print anything with it. For example, this prints "cats": echo -n c ; echo -n a ; echo -n t ; echo s
If it was echo 2 ; echo 3, it would output 2 in line 1 and 3 in line 2. By doing -n to all of these except the last it would bring all the characters to line 2. So -(line1)n(line2) becomes (line1)-n(line2)

Comment: Just some explanation about how it works ^^^

Answer (score 2):

To extend @A.B's answer, the only portable way to use `echo` is to refrain from using any options like `-n`. Consider use `printf` instead where available. [This reference page](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/echo+printf/) provides more details and explains very well when and how `echo` and `printf` should be used:

> Nowadays, echo(1) is only portable if you omit flags and escape sequences. 
>   Use printf(1) instead, if you need more than plain text.

Comment: I've you're gonna extend an answer, please edit the answer.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a good idea to alter someone else's answer to the point when it will have more text from me than from the original author.

Answer (score 1):

Three other ways:

```
$ echo -e '\x2dn' # ASCII hexadecimal value
-n
$ echo -e '\u002dn' # Unicode code point
-n
$ echo -e '\u2dn' # Unicode code point shortened
-n
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run

```
printf -n;echo
```

*Tested in Busybox Ash*

Comment: Ash? Ash? POKEMON i mean, what?

Comment: I ran 'busybox ash'

Comment: Say "Busybox" or "Busybox Ash". Not just "Ash" beacuse people may think of that pokemon character or the ******* ash from volcanoes.

Comment: Better. alt255alt255

Comment: @StarOS `ash` is the name of the Almquist Shell.